# Crashing with Xcode 4.2 when I click on XIB files

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, ipad, cydia

I have been using Xcode 4.2 for the past month without incident. Two days ago I went back into my project to add some navbars to my app. When I clicked on .XIB (Either one) xcode came crashing down.

I tried launching a new project but it ended up with the same exact result. I sudo deleted xcode in its entirety and did a fresh installation. Still the problem persists unfortunately I cannot upgrade to the latest Xcode because the only mac I have access to is a 2006 macbook that is not compatible with Mountain Lion.

Below is my error message when Xcode launches.

It seems to be a cocoa issue but I am at a loss.

> ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-933/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:179
>   Details:  Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with
>   the iOS Simulator. "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (431) failed
>   to launch and exited with status (null), signal 5. Please check
>   Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool"
>   for further information. Function:
>   NSDistantObject
>   *IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool(IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime *) Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1} Hints:   None Backtrace:
>   0  0x00000000008c184b -[IDEAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in IDEKit)   1  0x0000000000061728 _DVTAssertionHandler (in
>   DVTFoundation)   2  0x00000000000746db _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in
>   DVTFoundation)   3  0x000000001cfb7871 IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   4  0x000000001cfb7332
>   IBAskClassInTargetRuntimeForValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshallerWithContext
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   5  0x000000001cfb7118
>   IBAskClassInTargetRuntimeForValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshallerWithContext
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   6  0x000000001cfb7087
>   IBAskClassInTargetRuntimeForValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshaller (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   7  0x000000001cfb6b57
>   IBUserPresentableStringForTargetedDeviceFamily (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   8  0x000000001cfe5ace
>   IBIPhoneOSSdkToDeploymentTargetMapping (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   9  0x000000001cfe5b22
>   IBIPhoneOSSdkToDeploymentTargetMapping (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)  10  0x000000001cfec7cf
>   IBUIControlEventTypeToUIControlEventMask (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)  11  0x000000001ca4f44d
>   -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibWarnings:forDocument:withComputationContext:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  12  0x000000001cdec864
>   -[NSView(IBAppKitViewIntegration) ibSwizzledNSViewWarnings:forDocument:withComputationContext:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)  13  0x000000001d00fbb2
>   IBUIViewSizeToFillView (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration) 
>   14  0x000000001d01a451 IBMakeBarButtonItemFromPasteboardView (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)  15  0x000000001c9efb44
>   -[IBDocument rebuildWarnings] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  16  0x000000001c9efd4a -[IBDocument buildWarningsIfNeeded] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  17  0x000000001c9efdae -[IBDocument warnings]
>   (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  18  0x000000001caa305e -[IBIssueProvider
>   updateWarningsForOpenDocument:filePath:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit) 
>   19  0x000000001c9c93e7 -[IBIssueProvider updateOpenDocuments] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  20  0x000000001caa2e85 __50-[IBIssueProvider
>   initWithIssueManager:extension:]_block_invoke_051 (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  21  0x00000000000210de
>   -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation) 
>   22  0x0000000096fe5acb NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)  23 
>   0x0000000096fca2b6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification)
>   didChangeValueForKey:] (in Foundation)  24  0x00000000007ec026
>   -[IDEDocumentController addDocument:] (in IDEKit)  25  0x000000000081104d +[IDEDocumentController retainEditorDocument:] (in
>   IDEKit)  26  0x0000000000a00375 +[IDEDocumentController
>   _retainedNewEditorDocumentWithClass:forURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:extension:error:]
>   (in IDEKit)  27  0x000000000081f0d0 +[IDEDocumentController
>   _retainedEditorDocumentForURL:type:error:] (in IDEKit)  28  0x000000000081ef25 +[IDEDocumentController
>   retainedEditorDocumentForNavigableItem:forUseWithWorkspaceDocument:error:]
>   (in IDEKit)  29  0x0000000000910acd
>   IDEUtilitySliceRetainedDocumentsForNavigableItems (in IDEKit)  30 
>   0x00000000007e3cb6 -[IDEUtilityArea _rebuildStackWithNavigableItems:]
>   (in IDEKit)  31  0x00000000007e30d0 -[IDEUtilityArea
>   _rebuildCategoriesAndStack] (in IDEKit)  32  0x00000000007e2e23 __41-[IDEUtilityArea initWithNibName:bundle:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEKit)  33  0x00000000001e7a55 -[DVTDelayedValidator doValidation:]
>   (in DVTKit)  34  0x0000000096fff86c __NSFirePerformWithOrder (in
>   Foundation)  35  0x0000000093db2dd2 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in
>   CoreFoundation)  36  0x0000000093d6eced __CFRunLoopRun (in
>   CoreFoundation)  37  0x0000000093d6e3c4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in
>   CoreFoundation)  38  0x0000000093d6e1f1 CFRunLoopRunInMode (in
>   CoreFoundation)  39  0x0000000090447e04 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in
>   HIToolbox)  40  0x0000000090447af5 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in
>   HIToolbox)  41  0x0000000090447a3e
>   BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)  42 
>   0x00000000987c6595 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)  43  0x00000000987c5dd6
>   -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)  44  0x00000000987881f3 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)  45 
>   0x0000000098780289 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)  46 
>   0x0000000000001f3d  47  0x0000000000000002

Comment: Have you tried deleting all the prefs too?

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't upgrade to xCode 4.4...

Do you use TimeMachine?

Try to rewind your complete system...